# Galaxy S4 refuses to gain signal after being disconnected for a period of time

Tags: cellular-radio, network-signal

So, the scenario is this: I have a Verizon Galaxy S4 (SCH-I545, Android 5.0.1). One of my work sites is an amazingly effective dead zone. No signal whatsoever. If I enter the dead zone for a few minutes and leave, everything is fine. However, if I stay in the dead zone for 30+min or so (as is often the case), and then leave the dead zone, the phone will still display empty bars with a little "x" indicating no signal. It will stay like this indefinitely. I could turn on and off mobile data. I could turn on and off airplane mode. The only thing that fixes it is restarting the phone.

It's as if, once the phone realizes there's no signal coming its way, it will just refuse to even check for more every several minutes.

Is there a way to force such a check?

Comment: Google helps (even on the wrong stackexchange ;-)): http://www.technobezz.com/fix-samsung-galaxy-s4-signal/